# R LightGBM ignores init_score when continuing training with init_model

Tags: r, lightgbm

**General description of my problem**

I am performing a Poisson regression using LightGBM in R.

I am using an "offset" for the training, similar to using log(time) in a GLM as the offset when modelling insurance claims because we want to ensure that expected value of the response is proportional to time.  I do this using the init_score parameter within lab.train().

I am using the "continue training" option in lgb.train (where you specify a value for init_model). This is because I want to build a "stumps" model first, and then continue training with a more complex model.  This is to help me identify potential interaction terms in the data.  This is just for background why I am doing this - not relevant to the specific issue described below.

However, when I continue training, the offset originally specified in the first model I build is no longer used by the fitting process.  I think init_model overrides any value of init_score, but init_model does NOT itself contain or allow for init_score.  So, as far as I can see, the init_score is totally lost from the fitting process once you continue training using init_model.

This means that the "starting point" when continuing to train a model is not the "finishing point" from the original model build.  e.g. in my example below, I want the poisson log-likelihood error metric for models 2 and 3 to "start" from where model 1 finished.  This isn't the case - but surely that is what "continue training" should deliver?

I have entered comments into the code below to explain the issue more clearly.

**Reproducible example**

```
library(lightgbm)
library(data.table)

# simulate some data
# z follows a Poisson distribution
# the mean of z is given by t * exp(x+y), where t is the "time exposed to risk"
# t is uniform(0,10)
# x and y are uniform(0,1)
# I want to specify log(t) using init_score in the lightGBM
# i.e. just like Poisson regression in insurance where log(t) is the offset in a GLM or GBM
n <- 10000   # number of rows
set.seed(42)
d <- data.table(t = runif(n,0,10), x = runif(n,0,1), y = runif(n,0,1))
d[, z := rpois(n, t * exp(x+y))]

# check weighted mean looks about right
# should get actual = 2.957188 and
# underlying = 2.939975
d[, list(actual = sum(z)/sum(t),
         underlying = sum(t * exp(x+y))/sum(t)),]

# build a lightGBM using 100 rounds and specify log(t) as init_score
feature_cols <- c('x','y')
dm <- as.matrix(d[, ..feature_cols])
l_train <- lgb.Dataset(dm, label=d[,z], free_raw_data = FALSE)
setinfo(l_train, "init_score", log(d$t))

params <- list(objective='poisson', metric = 'poisson')

lgbm_1 <- lgb.train(params = params,
                    valids = list(train = l_train),
                    data = l_train,
                    nrounds = 100,
                    num_leaves = 2,
                    bagging_fraction = 1,
                    bagging_freq = 1,
                    feature_fraction = 1,
                    learning_rate=0.2)

train_log_1 <- lgb.get.eval.result(lgbm_1, "train", 'poisson')


# get the model predictions and check that they are close to expected
# remember that we need to manually apply the init_score to get the prediction
# i.e. we need to add log(t) onto the raw score, or multiply the scaled prediction by t
# the predictions are all very close
d[, lgbm_predicted_1 := t*predict(lgbm_1, dm, raw_score = FALSE)]
d[, list(actual = sum(z)/sum(t),
         predicted_1 = sum(lgbm_predicted_1)/sum(t),
         underlying = sum(t * exp(x+y))/sum(t)),]


# save the model
lgb.save(lgbm_1, 'lgbm_1.txt')

# ATTEMPT A - CONTINUE TRAINING FROM MODEL 1
# don't change the init_score
# note iterations in console start at 101 because we are continuing training
# however, the error metric (poisson log likelihood)
# start from a totally different value to where the first model ended
lgbm_2 <- lgb.train(params = params,
                    init_model = 'lgbm_1.txt',
                    valids = list(train = l_train),
                    data = l_train,
                    nrounds = 100,
                    num_leaves = 2,
                    bagging_fraction = 1,
                    bagging_freq = 1,
                    feature_fraction = 1,
                    learning_rate=0.2)

train_log_2 <- lgb.get.eval.result(lgbm_2, "train", 'poisson')

# check predictions - predicted_2 are WAY TOO HIGH now!
# I think this is because lightGBM uses the predictions from the first model
# as the starting point for training
# but the predictions from model 1 DO NOT ALLOW FOR THE log(t) being the offset to the original model!
d[, lgbm_predicted_2 := t*predict(lgbm_2, dm, raw_score = FALSE)]
d[, list(actual = sum(z)/sum(t),
         predicted_1 = sum(lgbm_predicted_1)/sum(t),
         predicted_2 = sum(lgbm_predicted_2)/sum(t),
         underlying = sum(t * exp(x+y))/sum(t)),]


# ATTEMPT B - try init_score = 0?
# doesn't seem to make any difference
# so my hypothesis is that init_score is being ignored
# and over-written by the init_model
# but... how does the original init_score ever get back into the fitting process?
# init_score + init_model is a good stating point
# init_model on it's own is not
setinfo(l_train, "init_score", rep(0, nrow(d)))
lgbm_3 <- lgb.train(params = params,
                    valids = list(train = l_train),
                    init_model = 'lgbm_1.txt',
                    data = l_train,
                    nrounds = 100,
                    num_leaves = 2,
                    bagging_fraction = 1,
                    bagging_freq = 1,
                    feature_fraction = 1,
                    learning_rate=0.2)

train_log_3 <- lgb.get.eval.result(lgbm_3, "train", 'poisson')

# check predictions - models 2 and 3 are identical, the init_score made no difference
d[, lgbm_predicted_3 := t*predict(lgbm_3, dm, raw_score = FALSE)]
d[, list(actual = sum(z)/sum(t),
         predicted_1 = sum(lgbm_predicted_1)/sum(t),
         predicted_2 = sum(lgbm_predicted_2)/sum(t),
         predicted_3 = sum(lgbm_predicted_3)/sum(t),
         underlying = sum(t * exp(x+y))/sum(t)),]

# compare training logs
# question - why do V2 and V3 not start from the "finishing" point of V1?
# it's because the init_model is wrong, because it doesn't allow for the init_score
logs <- data.table(v1 = train_log_1, v2 = train_log_2, v3 = train_log_3)
```